# How to scale text (or font) in tikzpicture without scaling entire node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scale

I've used `scale=0.5` for some of the nodes to make text smaller but a change that code has undergone lately leaves me no choice but to look for a way to keep the node's original size (it is a fixed-width type of node). I don't consider using `\tiny`, or any of the standard font-size commands, since text looks nothing like `scale=0.5` with `\tiny` (code below is to confirm the difference). What can be done to scale the font of a node without affecting the drawing box of the node?

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset
    {%
        ORIGINAL/.style=
            {%
                draw,
                text width=50mm
            }
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path node[ORIGINAL](one)
            { % ORIGINAL TEXT-SIZE (MUST BE CUT IN HALF)
                hello world (original)
            };
        \path node
            [ORIGINAL,scale=0.5,below=2mm of one](two)
            { % BOTH, TEXT AND NODE ARE SCALED-DOWN (NO GOOD)
                hello world (scales node too)
            };
        \path node
            [ORIGINAL,font=\tiny,below=2mm of two   ]
            { % TEXT IS SMALLER BUT NOT ENOUGH AND LOOKS WEIRD (NO GOOD)
                hello world (not exactly right)
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this:

[image]

for text in second node i use label with scaled content:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset
    {%
        ORIGINAL/.style=
            {%
                draw,
                text width=50mm
            }
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[ORIGINAL](one)
            { % ORIGINAL TEXT-SIZE (MUST BE CUT IN HALF)
                hello world (original)
            };
        \node[ORIGINAL,below=2mm of one,
             label={[scale=0.5]center:hello world (doesn't scale node size!)}] (two)
            {   };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**addendum.**
new version of above *mwe* which consider your comments below:

[image]

for this image i redefine node style. now has two parameters: `text width` and `scale`. their values are for not scaled nodes set by `/.default`, for other nodes had to be written in used nodes options. this solution require `fit` tikz library:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, positioning}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\tikzset{%
     N/.style args = {#1/#2}{% N as node (original)
        text width=#1/#2, scale=#2,
        draw,
        outer sep=1mm,
        path picture={%
        \node[inner sep=1mm, draw,
              fit=(path picture bounding box)] {};
                      }
                        },
     N/.default = 50mm/1,
        }% end of tikzset
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[N] (one) {hello world (original)};
        \node[N=50mm/0.5,
              below=2mm of one] {\lipsum[11]};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you just define style for labels. similarly as for "ORIGINAL".

Comment: i will do asap, temporary i'm busy with other obligation ...

Comment: @bp2017, i'm back :-). see addendum in my answer. i'm convinced that it solve your demands.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another suggestion using `\scalebox`:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset
    {%
        ORIGINAL/.style=
            {%
                draw,
                text width=50mm
            }
    }
\newcommand*\scalenodetext[2][.5]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\revscale{1/.5}%
    \scalebox{#1}{\parbox{\revscale\linewidth}{#2}}%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[ORIGINAL](one)
            { % ORIGINAL TEXT-SIZE (MUST BE CUT IN HALF)
                hello world (original)
            };
        \node
            [ORIGINAL,below=2mm of one   ](two)
            { %
                \scalenodetext{hello world (scaled)}
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or if the height of the node should not change while the text is scaled:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset
    {%
        ORIGINAL/.style=
            {%
                draw,
                text width=50mm
            }
    }
\newsavebox\nodetext
\newcommand*\scalenodetext[2][.5]{%
    \savebox\nodetext{\parbox{\linewidth}{#2}}%
    \vphantom{\usebox\nodetext}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\revscale{1/.5}%
    \scalebox{#1}{\parbox{\revscale\linewidth}{#2}}%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[ORIGINAL](one)
            { % ORIGINAL TEXT-SIZE (MUST BE CUT IN HALF)
                hello world (original)
            };
        \node
            [ORIGINAL,below=2mm of one   ](two)
            { %
                \scalenodetext{hello world (scaled)}
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]